# how can i show echo result in same page of submiting form using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms

i made this simple code to update the database row, and **i want to show the result of all the echo statement in the same page of the submit form without reloading the page (using ajax).**

**Form HTML code:**

```
    <html>
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Update Status</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" action="update.php">
    <p>Order ID: <input type="text" name="T1" size="5" required></p>
    <p>Status:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <select size="1" name="D1">
    <option selected value="In Progresss">In Progresss</option>
    <option value="Finished">Finished</option>
    </select></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Update" name="B1"></p>
</form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**update.php file:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Update Status</title>
<?php
$connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","T00r", "sells");
// Check connection
if($connection->connect_errno){
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;;
}
//select database to use
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection,"sells");
if(!$db_select){
die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
$T1=$_POST['T1']; $D1=$_POST['D1'];

//check if Order ID is available
$check1=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT Order_ID FROM clients WHERE Order_ID = '$T1' ");
 if (mysqli_num_rows($check1) == 0) { 
echo "  <b> == No Order With This ID == </b>";
}
else {
//insert value into database
$sql=mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE Clients SET Status = '$D1' WHERE Order_ID = '$T1'");

//check if the Status is Updated
$check2=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT Status FROM clients WHERE Order_ID = '$T1' ");
//get the value of Satuts to check if it's equal to the input data
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check2)){
 if($row["Status"] != $D1){
echo "  <b> == Status Not Updated == </b>";
}
else echo"<b> == Status Updated == </b>";
}

if(!$sql){
die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
}


mysqli_close($connection);
?>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: so basically, you want your code to be converted from a working normal form submission (that refreshes), to an AJAX update? sorry thats too broad, and by they way, since you're using mysqli, just use prepared statements.

Comment: i just don't want the result to be displayed on another page (/update.php)

Comment: yes i understand, u need an xmlhttprequest on update.php instead of using the form action processing that you're having right now, on your button submit bind that and request to the server along with t1 and d1, then on response, echo that markup and present it on the client side, if you want an ajax request, you're going to need javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True, you should use AJAX. It's not that hard, try this:

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <title>Update Status</title>
    </head>
        <body>
        <form method="POST" id="updateForm" action="update.php">
        <p>Order ID: <input type="text" name="T1" size="5" required></p>
        <p>Status:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <select size="1" name="D1">
        <option selected value="In Progresss">In Progresss</option>
        <option value="Finished">Finished</option>
        </select></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Update" name="B1"></p>
        </form>
        <div id="ajaxResponse"></div>

        <!-- Include the JQuery library !-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>  
        <script>
            <!-- Add a listener. This will be invoked when the form is submitted, 'submit' is the action, and '#updateForm' is the context it is listening !-->
            $(document).on('submit','#updateForm',function(e){

                <!-- This stops the original event. So that's the original submit action of the form. !-->
                e.preventDefault();

                <!-- Get the form data and serialize it into an array. !-->
                var data = $('#updateForm').serializeArray();

                <!-- The AJAX request. '.post' indicates that it should be a POST request. 'data' add the serialized array in the POST request. 'htmlResponse' is the response you get from the POST request, in your case your echo rules.  !-->
                $.post('update.php',data,function(htmlResponse){
                    <!-- The POST request is finished and the response is putted in the htmlResponse variable. So display this by setting the content(html) of the ajaxResponse div to the htmlResponse variable  
                    $('#ajaxResponse').html(htmlResponse);
                });
            });
        </script>

        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: thanks that does exactly what i want, but can u please explain to me how this code work?

Comment: Sure, one sec, let me add in my answer!

Comment: thanks a lot :) and it would be better if add the explanation inside the code as a comment so i can know what does each line does.

Comment: I added some comments. If you need more information, just let me know!

Comment: thank you :) now it is very clear and i get the idea :)